# Vue plugin with Typescript - Cannot read property '_init' of null

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to create Vue plugin containing a few reusable components. I want to create this using TypeScript. There are my files:

---

*components/SampleButton.vue*

```
<template>
  <button>Sample button</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'sample-button',
});
</script>
```

---

*main.ts*

```
import SampleButton from './components/SampleButton.vue';

export {
  SampleButton,
};

export default {
  install(Vue: any, _options: object = {}): void {
    Vue.component(SampleButton.name, SampleButton);
  },
};
```

---

*shims-vue.d.ts*

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';

  export default Vue;
}
```

---

Plugin building is successful, but when I try to user the plugin in my app I get an error:

```
import MyPlugin from 'my-plugin'

Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

[image]

Please help me find a mistake :)

Comment: Ever solve this?